# List of Resharper Default Formatting and Rules

Tags: resharper

I'm trying to find a list of all the default formatting and rules that Resharper enforces.

Unfortunately, I'm not having any luck.

We use the tool, but want to provide a document of standards to new hires so they can view the standards prior to coding.

Comment: imho this is badly needed. Just because it is boring does not mean it is unjustified. It is fine to say, that it is not because you can just look through the rules settings, however most large shops require documentation and discussion of "what is the default" and "is this rule appropriate to the SDLC as defined by my organisation"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the ReSharper menu, then Options, you'll find the current rules and conventions ReSharper is using for this solution. Of particular importance are:

**Code Inspection->Inspection Severity:** Shows the severity of things that ReSharper detects in code. The more things that are warnings or errors, the more closely you will have to conform code to ReSharper's conventions in order to get the file to "go green", or even to compile. The hierarchy is:

- Do Not Show - self-explanatory, ignores the inspection
- Hint - Does not show on sidebar, shows as dotted line under code in question. Good example: using "var" when the line of code doesn't otherwise explicitly specify the type being assigned.
- Suggestion - Shows on sidebar as green tick, code in question has green underline. Good examples: use of "var" when type is explicitly defined in the assignment, member visibility.
- Warning - Shows on sidebar as yellow tick, code in question underlined blue, or text is faded color. Naming convention violations, redundant keywords or qualifiers, unused code members.
- Error - Red sidebar tick, code in question either red text or underlined red. By default, nothing that wouldn't cause a compilation error is marked as a ReSharper error, but you can prevent compilation by "promoting" lower-priority inspections to errors.

**Languages->Naming Style:** This section shows you how ReSharper will expect various types of code member names to be formatted. The "Advanced settings" option also contains the "abbreviations list", which is basically a list of exceptions to the normal camel-casing conventions. By default, all format inconsistencies are warnings, and I do not see a way in 5.1 (the version I use) to change the severity of this.

EDIT: Here's a list of inspections and their default severities for RS 4.5, which is a few versions back but should still have the "meat" of ReSharper's C# inspections. http://unintelligible.org/blog/2010/05/24/resharper-45-inspection-severity-list/

Beyond this, even JetBrains simply refers you to the Options window if you want to see the list of inspections for your current language. So, if you want something more up-to-date, you may have to do it yourself. If you do, be sure to post it somewhere so others don't have to repeat your work.

Comment: But is there a list somewhere of what all the defaults are?  Rather than me copying all that information into a document from the settings?

Comment: I'm looking. If there is a place that lists all the defaults I would expect it to be on the JetBrains site, but the documentation doesn't seem to have anything this explicit.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO company coding standard is more than just formatting. It usually includes project organization conventions, library usage guidelines, etc. Listing every possible formatting rule ReSharper knows about will make it quite long and boring. Few examples for common constructs (which you can copy from bottom part of formatting setup window) should suffice. Providing them with short rationale should not be too hard to do manually.

Comment: I agree, but it's not my call.