# Where can I download a naming standard/ coding standard for Resharper?

Tags: c#, resharper

I am using Resharper 6, my team is asking for a coding standard to follow, I thought it would be simplier if I can just find the exisiting Resharper one I follow, send to others.

anyone could help please? Thanks

Comment: Why not just follow the default ReSharper conventions?

Comment: I think the request is for a document that states what the default R# configuration is?

Comment: Check Resharper online help: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Introduction__Index.html

Comment: Ah ok. I think I just misunderstood the question. Nevermind.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8806278/275751

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have 6.1 version(In previous version it was different)
In VS's toolbar:
Resharper > Manage Options... and there you can import/export any Resharper settings.

Comment: if there is any documentation in pdf, it would be fantastic

Comment: I don't think there is, it has already been asked for - http://stackoverflow.com/q/8806278/275751